# How do I filter the table() function in R when I pass two inputs in table(A,B)

Tags: r

I trying to make a heatmap of a subsection of a frequency table. How do I filter the table() function in R when I pass two inputs in table(A,B).

I tried
something like

```
tbl <-  table(A,B)
tbl[tbl>=10]
```

But i just get back the frequencies without the information of what it is.

Comment: what is your expected output? It seems to me that you can't just filter the values in the table: how would you hide a row, based on which column being greater than 10?. That said, you can check if this produces what you want: `tbl * as.numeric(tbl >= 10)` (it keeps values >= 10, "dropping" those less than.

Comment: You expect the `table` output to be a data frame, but it's more matrix-alike. Ever evaluated what's in your brackets `tbl >= 1`?

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way

```
tbl <- as.data.frame(table(A, B))
```

It should gave you three columns `data.frame`: `A`, `B`, `Freq` which should be sufficient for your heatmap with code similar to this sample working example

```
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

n <- 10000
A <- stri_rand_shuffle(stri_rand_strings(n, 1, '[a-z]'))
B <- stri_rand_shuffle(stri_rand_strings(n, 1, '[a-z]'))

tbl <- as.data.frame(table(A, B)) %>%
  arrange(A, B) %>%
  filter(Freq >= 10)
ggplot(data = tbl, aes(x = A, y = B, fill = Freq)) +
  geom_tile()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you were into tidyverse and R 4.x (native pipe operator), then another way would be to use the `uncount()` function together with `pivot_wider()`

```
with(tbl ,
  table(A , B
) |>  
  as.data.frame() |> 
  uncount(Freq) |>
  
  count(A , B, sort = TRUE) |> 
  filter(n >= 10) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "A", values_from = "n", values_fill = 0)  |>  
  filter(`some colname from A` > 0) # if you need a column-specific second filter
```

Admittedly, this is convoluted. It mixes tidyverse and base R. To continue with base R you could add a dummy variable column with a constant vaue 1, and call `table()`  and `prop.table()` again.

Alternatively you could use  100% tidyverse-style , avoiding a call to `table()`:

```
tbl |>
  count(A , B, sort = TRUE) |> 
  filter(n >= 10) |> 
  # you could also use names_from = "B" here
  pivot_wider(names_from = "A", values_from = "n", values_fill = 0)  |>  
  filter(`A_somecolumnname` > 0)  # even for more specific filtering.
```